# Can I capture JSON payload from a HttpRequest during automation testing(JUnit or TestNG with Selenium)?

Tags: java, selenium, http, automated-tests, fiddler

I am testing a website. In short, I need to do this: I go somewhere with Selenium during a test and click a button. This button triggers an Apache HttpRequest (Http, not Https) to be executed with a generated JSON payload. I need to save this payload somewhere and after the request has been sent, to use some data from it for further testing. The thing is, I do not know beforehand what exactly the backend will generate and it isn't save in any db I have access to. Is Fiddler applicable here? I'm new to it and as I understand it works with GUI only, but I need the test to run automated. Are there any other tools which could help?

Comment: Look into BrowserMob proxy with selenium.

Comment: Any proxy can be used, but as Fiddler bases on .Net and interfacing from Java to .Net is not that easy I would prefer a Java based proxy you can directly start within your unit test.